Firebase push notifications doesn't update badge with open app
I wrote the function to send push notifications with badge update on icon for ios (flutter app). When the application is closed everything works correctly, but if I am in open application then the badge does not change
I read firebase doc and try change my func to different methods
def send_multicast_notification(tokens, title, body, event_id=None, ncount=0):
    message = MulticastMessage(
        tokens=tokens,
        apns=APNSConfig(
            payload=APNSPayload(
                aps=Aps(
                    badge=4,
                    content_available=True,
                )
            )
        ),
    )

    try:
        response = send_each_for_multicast(message)
        print('Successfully sent message:', response)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error sending message:', str(e))

